# How to prove the following statement: if $\mu=\sum\mu_n$ and $\mu_n \ll m$ for all $n$ ($m$=Lebesgue measure) then $\mu \ll m$

Tags: measure-theory

How to prove: If $\mu=\sum\mu_n$ and $\mu_n \ll m$ for all $n$ then $\mu \ll m$.
where $\mu_n \ll m$ means measure $\mu$ is absolutely continuous with respect o Lebesgue measure $m$.

Comment: the result is trivial, you only need to use the definition of $a\ll b$

Comment: Suppose $\mu=\sum\mu_n$ and $\mu_n \ll m$ for all $n$. Then, for all $E$ measurable such that $m(E)=0$, we have that $\mu_n(E)=0$ for all $n$. So $\mu(E)=\sum\mu_n(E)=0$, so we have that $\mu \ll m$.